# How can I sequentially fade in several divs?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a sequential fadeIn using jQuery.
Essentially, when the page loads I want three words to fadeIn, one after the other.
For example:
Page loads -> Word1 fades in -> Word2 fades in -> Word3 fades in.
The following word would fade in only after the preceding word had finished fading in.
Each individual word is in its own div at the moment.
This is what I've got so far, but for some reason it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#word1').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#word2').delay(1500).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#word3').delay(2500).fadeIn(1000);
});
</script>

<div id="word1">Word 1</div>
<div id="word2">Word 2</div>
<div id="word3">Word 3</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not working how? I added a div{display:none;} rule, and it seems OK to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/xudaR/1/)

One way you could do it would be to use an `each()` loop and fade them in:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#word1, #word2, #word3').each(function(fadeInDiv) {
     $(this).delay(fadeInDiv * 500).fadeIn(1000);
   });
});
```

Note I'm supplying a parameter, `fadeInDiv`, which will increment for each of the three elements (returns `0`, `1`, `2`) and multiplying that by the delay, so you will get the delay incrementing accordingly (`0`, `500`, `1000`) etc.

Of course, this scales very easily as you'd imagine - [**here's another jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xudaR/9/) using a class `word` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You could edit your markup and add classes to your `word` divs:

```
<div id="word1" class="words">Word 1</div>
<div id="word2" class="words">Word 2</div>
<div id="word3" class="words">Word 3</div>
```

And then call this JavaScript:

```
$('.words').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(500*(i+1)).fadeIn(1000); //Uses the each methods index+1 to create a multiplier on the delay
});
```

If you didn't add a new `class`, the following would work:

```
$('#word1, #word2, #word3').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(500*(i+1)).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYqP5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery’s `fadeIn()` function takes a second argument, `complete`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), which is a function that will be called when the fade has finished.

So, maybe try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $word1 = $('#word1'),
        $word2 = $('#word2'),
        $word3 = $('#word3');

    $word1.delay(500).fadeIn(1000,function () {
        $word2.fadeIn(1000, function () {
            $word3.fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel,

You don't have to rely on delays.

The "proper" way to execute sequential animations is to exploit the `promise` available on jQuery's standard `fx` animation queue, allowing you to trigger whatever you like on completion of animations - in this case fading in the next word.

The code can be written on a number of ways, here's one :

```
function f(baseID, n, t) {
    var jq = $("#" + baseID + n);
    if(jq.length) {
        jq.fadeIn(t).promise().done(function() {
            f(baseID, n+1, t);
        });
    }
};

f('word', 1, 1000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y7WQH/)**

Written like this, function `f()` is reusable. You could, for example, have two separate series of fade-ins as follows :

```
f('word', 1, 1000);
f('other', 1, 1000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y7WQH/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example so you can fade out only the desired subelements of a given element by using `.children().each()` jquery function. You can reuse the code pretty easily indeed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#maincontentinner").children().each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i++) * 200).fadeIn().delay(200);
  });
});
```

```css
 #maincontentinner > * {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<H1>Este texto no será cambiado</H1>
<div id="maincontentinner">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <ul>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>este texto no cambiará</p>
```