# Fade in a large amount of objects sequentially with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to get 900 dots to fade in one after the other. My current code generates them from one single div and then assigns a number class to them.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function generate() {    
        var circle = $('.circle');
        var container = $('#container');
        for (var i = 0; i <= 900; i++) {
            circle.clone().attr('class', 'circle ' + i).appendTo(container);
        }
    }
    
    generate();
});
```

```html
 <style>
  #container {
 width: 1250px; 
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:1770px; 
 height: 670px;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color:pink;
 position:relative;
  }
  .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px; 
 background-color:#8AB5DC;
 margin:10px;
 float:left;
  }

 
  
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="container">
 <div class="circle">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This seems fairly computationally intense to rely on javascript to generate on the DOM. Have you tried looking into Canvas 2D?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I sequentially fade in several divs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867887/how-can-i-sequentially-fade-in-several-divs)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function generate() {
        var duration = 400;
        var delayFactor = 40;
        var circle = $('.circle');
        var container = $('#container');
        for (var i = 0; i <= 900; i++) {
            circle.clone().attr('class', 'circle ' + i).appendTo(container).hide();
        }
        $('.circle').each(function (index) {
            $(this).delay(index * delayFactor).fadeIn(duration);
        });
    }
    generate();
});
```

```css
#container {
    width: 1250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1770px;
    height: 670px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:pink;
    position:relative;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color:#8AB5DC;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Play with the **`duration`** and **`delayFactor`** values. Hope this helps.